# Web services for current dollar rate, gold rate and silver rate on my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, google-finance-api, yahoo-finance

Platform: .NET with C# Windows Application

I am looking for a API / Webservice(s) that could fetch me these things

1. The current dollar rate.
2. The current gold rate.
3. The current silver rate.

Comment: There are a lot of services that provide this. I use OANDA. It depends on how stale you can live with these prices being. If you require live market data, then you will probably (definitely) have to go with a paid for services - and these don't come cheap. However, if you're happy with slightly stale data then look at OANDA or CQG.

Comment: How did you get the price finally.Was it from the abive url. If so where didi you get what the symbols mean

Comment: This would be an acceptable question at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com